# Populating a collection in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.7.2

How to populate collection through the interface?
Here is the XAML:

```
    <local:ViewModel>
        <local:Test Text="Hmm!"/>
    </local:ViewModel>
```

Here is the model which works:

```
[ContentProperty("Tests")]
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Test> Tests { get; } = new List<Test>();
}
```

Where:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to go with the interface though:

```
[ContentProperty("Tests")]
public class ViewModel
{
    public IList<Test> Tests { get; } = new List<Test>();
}
```

It does not compile unfortunately:

> Cannot set content property 'Tests' on element 'ViewModel'. 'Tests'
>   has incorrect access level or its assembly does not allow access.

I actually instantiate a PostSharp `AdvisableCollection<T>` and would not like client code to depend on it.

Comment: Looks like the error implies that you need to add set accessor to your Tests, as you're trying to set the collection in your xaml?

Comment: Nope, it's not the case. It adds to `List<T> { get; }`, but fails to compile `IList<T> { get; }`.

Comment: Just to clarify - WPF works fine with { get; } only when populating collection properties. It is a common mistake to think otherwise. Unfortunately there is no proper support for generic interfaces though - this tech is in zombie mode for way too long.

Answer (score 0):

The XAML is processed using the type definitions present in the XAML. It does not have visibility of the instances actually being used.

The XAML processor uses the non-generic `IList` interface to add items to a collection and the processor generates code. Because the `IList<T>` interface does not implement either of these interfaces, items cannot be added to the collection in XAML. `List<T>` implements the `IList` interface which is why it compiles as you expect.

If `AdvisableCollection<T>` implements `IList` you could simply use `IList` which might be undesirable because you lose the strongly typed interface.

If `AdvisableCollection<T>` implements a rather universal collection type like `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` or `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`, you could use those types for the definition. While not as generic, still pretty universal and those types have a limited number of additional properties and methods which make changing between `IList<T>` types pretty simple and straightforward.

Another possible option is implementing a wrapper class that inherits both the `IList` and `IList<T>` interfaces. This has the advantage of being able to work with any concrete type that implements `IList<T>` while having a strongly typed collection.